# kubernetes pod 'CrashLoopBackOff' error: cpu.max: no such file or directory: unknowncontainer

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia-jetson, containerd

I initiated a Kubernetes cluster on my master node and aimed to incorporate the Jetson AGX Orin as an edge node. Using keadm join, I successfully added the Orin device to the cluster, and it appears as 'Ready' from the master node. However, attempting to deploy a basic application onto Orin using kubectl from the master node results in a 'CrashLoopBackOff' status.

When I describe the pod for debugging:

```
Containers:
nginx:
Container ID: containerd://a57da990b1ffe2f3aa1445311d57ed0a99e703d81a496a1bb519f244ce1ce03f
Image: nginx:1.14.2
Image ID: docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:f7988fb6c02e0ce69257d9bd9cf37ae20a60f1df7563c3a2a6abe24160306b8d
Port: 80/TCP
Host Port: 0/TCP
State: Waiting
Reason: CrashLoopBackOff
Last State: Terminated
Reason: StartError
Message: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: openat2 /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod7654d855_494c_47c2_9ff6_f107799958dc.slice:cri-containerd:6b6fc5b2451465631739e98a758a21aa941d10040d36db93c7a5c892f0080ed7/cpu.max: no such file or directory: unknown
```

[There are many cpu files in this path but cpu.max is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kPgG.png)

The default containerd version was 1.6.27. I installed 1.6.12 and 1.7.12 versions but it did not resolve the issue.
I installed keadm v1.14.3, 1.14.4 and 1.15.1 on the Orin but all of them gave the same results.
I am not so familar with cgroup drivers. So I am not sure if the issue is related to cgroup driver on the Orin device because I also added Jetson Nano as an edge device to my cluster and did not come across this issue. (both of them had 'cgoupfs' driver is their edgecore.yaml files). Anyway, I changed Orin cgroup driver from cgroupfs to systemd in the edgecore.yaml file as suggested in https://kubeedge.io/docs/faq/setup/ 'cgroup driver does not match' issue.
None of the above adjustments resolved the issue.

```
Jetson Orin AGX
Kernel Version: 5.15.122-tegra
OS Image: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Operating System: linux
Architecture: aarch64
```

I received pod **'CrashLoopBackOff'** error.
I expect to run the pod successfully and get 'Running' status.